# Android: Where to schedule a job?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I'm using LiveData+Room+ViewModel to build a simple kotlin app. The main activity (which presents a list) is getting the required data from a ViewModel which is getting the info from a database (the data is transformed before being consumed by the activity). Now, I need to allow the user to refresh the data through a swipe. When that happens, the app should check if the current connection can be used for that and if it can't, then the app should schedule a job.

Currently, I'm delegating this work (check the current connection and the eventual job scheduling) to my ViewModel. It looks like this:

```
fun tryToRefreshDataFromService(){
    //first, check if there's network
    //If there is, call web service and then update db
    //if no network, schedule a job and try to refresh from the database
    if(canGetDataFromNetwork()){
        Timber.d("With network access, getting data from web services")
        WebServiceAsyncTask(newsManager).execute()
    }
    else{
        //schedule job for refreshing
        //no network access, setting up job
        Timber.d("No network access, setting up job")
        scheduleJob()
    }
}
```

The activity will then be able to call the method from within a helper method (which handles the swiper refresh event):

```
private fun recoverDataForTabs(swiper: SwipeRefreshLayout? = null){
    _swiper = swiper //for clearing
    _viewModel.tryToRefreshDataFromService()
}
```

However, it [seems](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-and-livedata-patterns-antipatterns-21efaef74a54) like this is really a bad idea because it seems like ViewModels shouldn't know anything about Android framework classes (and that ends up being required for this case). So, does this mean that I should update my code so that the network checking + job scheduling is done from the activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject framework-related objects into your `ViewModels`. For example:

```
class MyViewModel(val networkChecker: IMyNetworkChecker, val jobSetter: IMyJobSetter, ...) {

    fun tryToRefreshDataFromService(){
        if(networkChecker.canGetDataFromNetwork()){
            Timber.d("With network access, getting data from web services")
            WebServiceAsyncTask(newsManager).execute()
        }
        else{
            Timber.d("No network access, setting up job")
            jobSetter.scheduleJob()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. So you're saying to abstract it into an interface and then the implementation would hold the android related stuff?

Comment: @Luis Abreu, yes. It doesn't need to be an interface, but my point is to make the view model call a method without knowing the actual implementation of it.